# C# WinForm DataGridView Header

Tags: c#

I need to find **in the header** of DataGridView the column number by column name.
For example: Write "Address" and get 3 (in the attached example picture)
[DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmNpr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
var urColumnPosition =  Datagridview.Columns["Address"].Index + 1
```